# Merging two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, join, merge

I am trying to create a new array from two current arrays. Tried array_merge, but it will not give me what I want. `$array1` is a list of keys that I pass to a function. `$array2` holds the results from that function, but doesn't contain any non-available resuls for keys. So, I want to make sure that all requested keys comes out with 'null':ed values, as according to the shown `$result` array.

It goes a little something like this:

```
$array1 = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4');

$array2 = array(
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3'
);
```

Here's the result I want:

```
$result = array(
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3',
    'item4' => ''  
);
```

It can be done this way, but I don't think that it's a good solution - I really don't like to take the easy way out and suppress PHP errors by adding @:s in the code. This sample would obviously throw errors since `'item4'` is not in `$array2`, based on the example.

```
foreach ($keys as $k => $v){
    @$array[$v] = $items[$v]; 
}
```

So, what's the fastest (performance-wise) way to accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_fill_keys` will build you a nice array you can use in `array_merge`:

```
array_merge(array_fill_keys($array1, ''), $array2);
```

Or, instead of array_merge, you can use the `+` op which performs a union:

```
$array2 + array_fill_keys($array1, '');
```

This one works with numerical keys or mixed numerical/strings :)

Comment: @Industrial: It works for your example! ;)  Does the array contain only numeric keys or a mixture?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, man! The array contains both numbers and characters

Comment: @Industrial - Updated the answer. `+` seems to work fine with a mixed array.

Comment: Great stuff! That was more clever than I ever would have come up with! Thanks a lot for your help, Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing errors check that the key exits using array_key_exists

```
<?php
 foreach($array1 as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
        $result[$key] = $array2[$key];
    } else {
        $result[$key] = null;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge one or more arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_fill_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php):

```
$result = array_merge(
    array_array_fill_keys($array1,''),
    $array2
);
```

You should be aware that with array_merge the value in the latter array overwrite the first ones only if the keys are not numbers and, therefore, this method will not work if $array1 contains numerical values. For example with the following values in input, this code will not work properly:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3);
$array2 = array("hi"=>"world",2=>"test","other"=>"empty");
```

Will produce the following:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["hi"]=>
  string(5) "world"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["other"]=>
  string(5) "empty"
```

}

If you are sure that the array keys are all literals you can use it without worries

Comment: Hi! It's the literal parts that worries me. What happens when not?

Answer (score 0):

In the cases where that won't work, such you're not using array_fill_keys or a similar function that returns returns an array type, you can cast to array.

```
$array1 = (array)$array2 + (array)$array1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at array_combine? Here's a link: [PHP reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

It seems to do exactly what you want, with one caveat: If the two arrays aren't of equal size, it does nothing. If it is guaranteed that your array of keys will always be longer than your array of values, you could just pad the values array with null values until both arrays are of equal size before calling array_combine.

Comment: Array_combine doesn't join arrays in that fashion.  It builds an associate array from two arrays.  One for the keys and one for the values.